# Count number of Blobs

Tags: c#, aforge

I am working on image processing using Aforge C#. How can I count number of blobs (white blobs on black blackbround)  in an image. The image have a circular white blob (image is already in binary format). Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: If you do this manually you will need to locate all white pixel then you will need to group them by distance. So every white pixel that touches another pixel should be regarded as part of one blob.

Answer (score 0):

If you still are searching for the answer, try:

```
BlobCounterBase bc = new BlobCounter();
bc.FilterBlobs = true;
bc.MinWidth = N; //give required value or ignore
bc.MinHeight = M; //give required value  or ignore
bc.CoupledSizeFiltering = true; // if value are given and if you want both Width and Height to be applied as a constraint to identify blob, set it to true
bc.ProcessImage(image);
Blob[] blobs = bc.GetObjectsInformation();
```

`blobs.Count` will give you count of blobs.